# Add multiple registers relationship with one register MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, view, partial-views, relationship

I'm the new MVC developer, but I'm C# programmer in long time.

On my system i need add multiple telephone numbers and link with one customer.
This is my flow:

1º Save my customer data.
2º Add multiple phone number to my recent customer

This flow, cant be on more of one page.
I need save the customer and after save all phone number, linking with the customer.

This is my Customer table:
IdCliente int,
Nome varchar(100),
isAtivo bit

and this is my Telephone Number table:
IdTelefone int autoincrement,
IdPessoa int (FK with Customer table),
Number bigint

When I save the telefone number, I need pass the IdCustomer of my recent customer.

My view is split on two parts.
The Customer Page with de Customer Data, and one PartialView with de Telephone Number Data.

This is my HTML

```
@model MSX_Contabil.Models.PESSOA_TB
@{    ViewBag.Title = "MSX Contail - Cadastro de Pessoa";
}
<h2>
    Cadastro de pessoa</h2>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#DT_NASCIMENTO").datepicker();
        $("#accordion").accordion();
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    }); 
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 25%">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID_TIPO_PESSOA, "Tipo pessoa")<label>*</label>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 25%">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NM_PESSOA, "Nome")<label>*</label>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 25%">
            </td>
            <td style="width: 25%">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList("ID_TIPO_PESSOA", "-- selecione --")
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_TIPO_PESSOA, "Campo obrigatório")
            </td>
            <td colspan="3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NM_PESSOA)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NM_PESSOA, "Campo obrigatório")
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DT_NASCIMENTO, "Data nascimento")<label>*</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID_ESTADO_CIVIL, "Estado civil")
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FL_ATIVO, "Pessoa ativa")
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DT_NASCIMENTO)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DT_NASCIMENTO, "Campo obrigatório")
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList("ID_ESTADO_CIVIL", "-- selecione --")
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FL_ATIVO)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FL_ATIVO)
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>



    if (ViewBag.PessoaSalva != true)
    {
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Salvar" />
        <input type="submit" value="Cancelar" onclick="javascript:window.navigate('/Pessoa'); return false;" />
    </p>
    }
}
@if (ViewBag.PessoaSalva == true)
{
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#Telefone">Telefones</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Documento">Documentos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Endereco">Endereços</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Email">E-mails</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Contato">Contatos</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="Telefone">
            <p>
                @Html.Partial("TelefonePessoa", new MSX_Contabil.Models.TELEFONE_PESSOA_TB())
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="Document">
        </div>
        <div id="Endereco">
        </div>
        <div id="Email">
        </div>
        <div id="Contato">
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

this is my Partial View when is my Telephone Number Page.

```
@model MSX_Contabil.Models.TELEFONE_PESSOA_TB
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Inserir", "TelefonePessoa", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ID_OPERADORA_TELEFONIA, "Operadora")
            </td>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.NU_TELEFONE, "Número")
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NU_RAMAL, "Ramal")
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ID_OPERADORA_TELEFONIA)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID_OPERADORA_TELEFONIA)
            </td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NU_TELEFONE)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NU_TELEFONE)
            </td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.NU_RAMAL)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NU_RAMAL)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DS_OBSERVACAO, "Observação")
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.DS_OBSERVACAO)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DS_OBSERVACAO)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Adicionar" id="btnSalvar" />
    </p>

}
```

this is my Controller code.

```
CustomerController:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MSX_Contabil.Models;

namespace MSX_Contabil.Controllers
{
    public class PessoaController : Controller
    {
        private MSXContabilEntities db = new MSXContabilEntities();

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var pessoa_tb = db.PESSOA_TB.Include("TIPO_PESSOA_TB");
            return View(pessoa_tb.ToList());
        }

        public ViewResult Details(string guid)
        {
            PESSOA_TB pessoa_tb = db.PESSOA_TB.Single(p => p.CD_IDENTIFICACAO == guid);
            return View(pessoa_tb);
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.ID_TIPO_PESSOA = new SelectList(db.TIPO_PESSOA_TB, "ID_TIPO_PESSOA", "NM_TIPO_PESSOA");
            ViewBag.ID_ESTADO_CIVIL = new SelectList(db.ESTADO_CIVIL_TB, "ID_ESTADO_CIVIL", "NM_ESTADO_CIVIL");
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(PESSOA_TB pessoa_tb)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)

            {
                pessoa_tb.CD_IDENTIFICACAO = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                db.PESSOA_TB.AddObject(pessoa_tb);
                db.SaveChanges();
                pessoa_tb.CD_PESSOA = pessoa_tb.ID_PESSOA.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
                db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(pessoa_tb, EntityState.Modified);
                db.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.PessoaSalva = true;
                ViewBag.ID_PESSOA = pessoa_tb.ID_PESSOA;
                RouteData.Values.Add("ID_PESSOA", pessoa_tb.ID_PESSOA);
            }

            ViewBag.ID_TIPO_PESSOA = new SelectList(db.TIPO_PESSOA_TB, "ID_TIPO_PESSOA", "NM_TIPO_PESSOA", pessoa_tb.ID_TIPO_PESSOA);
            ViewBag.ID_ESTADO_CIVIL = new SelectList(db.ESTADO_CIVIL_TB, "ID_ESTADO_CIVIL", "NM_ESTADO_CIVIL");
            return View(pessoa_tb);
        }

        public ActionResult Edit(string guid)
        {
            PESSOA_TB pessoa_tb = db.PESSOA_TB.Single(p => p.CD_IDENTIFICACAO == guid);
            ViewBag.ID_TIPO_PESSOA = new SelectList(db.TIPO_PESSOA_TB, "ID_TIPO_PESSOA", "NM_TIPO_PESSOA", pessoa_tb.ID_TIPO_PESSOA);
            ViewBag.ID_ESTADO_CIVIL = new SelectList(db.ESTADO_CIVIL_TB, "ID_ESTADO_CIVIL", "NM_ESTADO_CIVIL");
            return View(pessoa_tb);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(PESSOA_TB pessoa_tb)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.PESSOA_TB.Attach(pessoa_tb);
                db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(pessoa_tb, EntityState.Modified);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.ID_TIPO_PESSOA = new SelectList(db.TIPO_PESSOA_TB, "ID_TIPO_PESSOA", "NM_TIPO_PESSOA", pessoa_tb.ID_TIPO_PESSOA);
            ViewBag.ID_ESTADO_CIVIL = new SelectList(db.ESTADO_CIVIL_TB, "ID_ESTADO_CIVIL", "NM_ESTADO_CIVIL");
            return View(pessoa_tb);
        }

        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            PESSOA_TB pessoa_tb = db.PESSOA_TB.Single(p => p.ID_PESSOA == id);
            return View(pessoa_tb);
        }

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            PESSOA_TB pessoa_tb = db.PESSOA_TB.Single(p => p.ID_PESSOA == id);
            db.PESSOA_TB.DeleteObject(pessoa_tb);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        public ActionResult Inativar(string guid)
        {
            PESSOA_TB pessoa_tb = db.PESSOA_TB.Single(u => u.CD_IDENTIFICACAO == guid);
            pessoa_tb.FL_ATIVO = (pessoa_tb.FL_ATIVO ? false : true);
            db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(pessoa_tb, EntityState.Modified);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

TelefoneNumberController:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MSX_Contabil.Models;

namespace MSX_Contabil.Controllers
{ 
    public class TelefonePessoaController : Controller
    {
        private MSXContabilEntities db = new MSXContabilEntities();

        //
        // GET: /TelefonePessoa/

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            var telefone_pessoa_tb = db.TELEFONE_PESSOA_TB.Include("PESSOA_TB");
            return View(telefone_pessoa_tb.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /TelefonePessoa/Details/5

        public ViewResult Details(int id)
        {
            TELEFONE_PESSOA_TB telefone_pessoa_tb = db.TELEFONE_PESSOA_TB.Single(t => t.ID_PESSOA == id);
            return View(telefone_pessoa_tb);
        }

        //
        // GET: /TelefonePessoa/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.ID_PESSOA = new SelectList(db.PESSOA_TB, "ID_PESSOA", "CD_PESSOA");
            return View();
        } 

        //
        // POST: /TelefonePessoa/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(TELEFONE_PESSOA_TB telefone_pessoa_tb)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.TELEFONE_PESSOA_TB.AddObject(telefone_pessoa_tb);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");  
            }

            ViewBag.ID_PESSOA = new SelectList(db.PESSOA_TB, "ID_PESSOA", "CD_PESSOA", telefone_pessoa_tb.ID_PESSOA);
            return View(telefone_pessoa_tb);
        }

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Inserir")]
        public ActionResult Inserir(TELEFONE_PESSOA_TB telefone_pessoa_tb)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                telefone_pessoa_tb.ID_PESSOA = Convert.ToInt32(RouteData.GetRequiredString("ID_PESSOA"));
                db.TELEFONE_PESSOA_TB.AddObject(telefone_pessoa_tb);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }

            ViewBag.ID_PESSOA = new SelectList(db.PESSOA_TB, "ID_PESSOA", "CD_PESSOA", telefone_pessoa_tb.ID_PESSOA);
            return View(telefone_pessoa_tb);
        }        

        //
        // GET: /TelefonePessoa/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            TELEFONE_PESSOA_TB telefone_pessoa_tb = db.TELEFONE_PESSOA_TB.Single(t => t.ID_PESSOA == id);
            ViewBag.ID_PESSOA = new SelectList(db.PESSOA_TB, "ID_PESSOA", "CD_PESSOA", telefone_pessoa_tb.ID_PESSOA);
            return View(telefone_pessoa_tb);
        }

        //
        // POST: /TelefonePessoa/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(TELEFONE_PESSOA_TB telefone_pessoa_tb)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.TELEFONE_PESSOA_TB.Attach(telefone_pessoa_tb);
                db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(telefone_pessoa_tb, EntityState.Modified);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.ID_PESSOA = new SelectList(db.PESSOA_TB, "ID_PESSOA", "CD_PESSOA", telefone_pessoa_tb.ID_PESSOA);
            return View(telefone_pessoa_tb);
        }

        //
        // GET: /TelefonePessoa/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            TELEFONE_PESSOA_TB telefone_pessoa_tb = db.TELEFONE_PESSOA_TB.Single(t => t.ID_PESSOA == id);
            return View(telefone_pessoa_tb);
        }

        //
        // POST: /TelefonePessoa/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {            
            TELEFONE_PESSOA_TB telefone_pessoa_tb = db.TELEFONE_PESSOA_TB.Single(t => t.ID_PESSOA == id);
            db.TELEFONE_PESSOA_TB.DeleteObject(telefone_pessoa_tb);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is way too much code. (Why do you need to show `Delete` and `Index` actions etc., etc. for your question?) Can you extract the pieces of code that are relevant to your question and explain where the problem is?

Comment: Can you please make it simple?

Comment: How I do to pass the IdCustomer that I add recent, to my PartialView to save the Telephone Number linked with my received Id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem!

I put a link to redirect to the view of the Phone Numbers passing the parameter IdCustomer and after I saved the Phone Number, I redirect to action Edit Customer passing his Id.

```
<p>
   @Html.ActionLink("Adicionar telefone", "Create", "TelefonePessoa", new { id = Model.ID_PESSOA, guid = Model.CD_IDENTIFICACAO }, null)
</p>
```

Code to save Phone Number:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(TELEFONE_PESSOA_TB telefone_pessoa_tb, int id, string guid)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       telefone_pessoa_tb.ID_PESSOA = id;
       db.TELEFONE_PESSOA_TB.AddObject(telefone_pessoa_tb);
       db.SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Pessoa", new { guid = guid });
    }

    ViewBag.ID_PESSOA = new SelectList(db.PESSOA_TB, "ID_PESSOA", "CD_PESSOA", telefone_pessoa_tb.ID_PESSOA);
    return View(telefone_pessoa_tb);
}
```